# Getting started with Firefox extension development 2013/2014

Tags: firefox

I have been reading now for hours about creating Firefox extensions. There are no good up to date tutorials that I can think of. Several methods exist to develop Firefox extensions but none of them seams to easily get you started and provide you with further information about how to develop your application. There are also mostly old tutorials and the official one has an "This article is in need of a technical review." warning on the top of it.

My goal extension is a simple tool to justify the Firefox settings and do some work. To get started I want to have a button to:

- start working offline
- clean all browser data
- change proxy settings
- start working online

In a good environment like Firefox this should be done in <55h right?:)

So how do I achieve this? What's the current best way to achieve this?

I don't want tips about existing extension just a modern way to get started and develop an extension that could do something like this.

Answer (score 0):

[Tutorials](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/tutorials/index.html) and [guides](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/index.html) are good for getting started. Then you have to dig up on several high and low level APIs and use what you need.

In your goal extension:

For the button take a look at [widget API](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/widget.html)

For changing work offline/online preference and for changing proxy settings you can use the [preferences/service API](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/modules/sdk/preferences/service.html) which changes about:config entries.

About clearing browser data, as far as I know (if someone else knows please edit or comment my answer) there is not an API but you can check other clear-browser-data restartless addons code, like [this one](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/files/browse/158451/file/resources/clear-all/lib/main.js#top) which use require("chrome") which is a kind of hack.